# How can I improve this program in a few lines of code?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, switch-statement, discord

I'm trying to create a discord bot that checks if the message contains the string stored in the array.
I tried using a for loop but it didn't work because it continued forever, I would like to reduce the lines of code, is there any way to do this?

```
switch {
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[0]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[0]
        currentDescription = descriptions[0]
        currentImage = images[0]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[1]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[1]
        currentDescription = descriptions[1]
        currentImage = images[1]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[2]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[2]
        currentDescription = descriptions[2]
        currentImage = images[2]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[3]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[3]
        currentDescription = descriptions[3]
        currentImage = images[3]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[4]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[4]
        currentDescription = descriptions[4]
        currentImage = images[4]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[5]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[5]
        currentDescription = descriptions[5]
        currentImage = images[5]
        isCorrect = true
    case strings.Contains(mContent, characterss[6]):
        currentCharacter = characterss[6]
        currentDescription = descriptions[6]
        currentImage = images[6]
        isCorrect = true
    }
```

Comment: Let me ask you this. Do see a _pattern_ here?

Comment: Yes, mine didn't work because I used len(characterss) instead of the number of the elements in total, idk actually why len didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```golang
for i := 0; i <= 6; i ++ {
    if strings.Contains(mContent, characeterss[i]) {
        currentCharacter = characterss[i]
        currentDescription = descriptions[i]
        currentImage = images[i]
        isCorrect = true
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help, actually I think mine didn't work because it had the len(characterss) instead of 6. I don't know why len didn't work tho